# Twisted: how-to bind a server to a specified IP address?

Tags: python, twisted

I want to have a twisted service (started via twistd) which listens to TCP/POST request on a specified port on a specified IP address. By now I have a twisted application which listens to port 8040 on localhost. It is running fine, but I want it to only listen to a certain IP address, say 10.0.0.78.

How-to manage that? This is a snippet of my code:

```
application = service.Application('SMS_Inbound')

smsInbound = resource.Resource()
smsInbound.putChild('75sms_inbound',ReceiveSMS(application))
smsInboundServer = internet.TCPServer(8001, webserver.Site(smsInbound))
smsInboundServer.setName("SMS Handling")
smsInboundServer.setServiceParent(application)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `interface` argument to `twisted.application.internet.TCPServer`:

```
smsInboundServer = internet.TCPServer(8001, webserver.Site(smsInbound),
    interface='10.0.0.78')
```

(Which it inherits from `reactor.listenTCP()`, since all the `t.a.i.*Server` classes really just forward to `reactor.listenXXX` for the appropriate protocol.)